# iOS 11 framework (CoreML) inside Playground Book

Tags: swift, swift-playground, coreml

I recently encountered a strange behavior of **Playground Books** when trying to access the **CoreML framework**.

First of all, CoreML does work with pure .playground files, as can be seen in Apple's example "MarsHabitatModel".

When copying the same source files inside a .playgroundbook, the Playground Book failed to compile and raises

> Error: MLModel is only available on iOS application extension 11.0 or
>   newer.

I ensured that the deployment target inside **Manifest.plist** file of the .playgroundbook was set to iOS11.0. Because of that, I am very unsure of whether or how CoreML can work inside a Playground Book.

Has anyone of you successfully integrated an iOS11 framework inside a playground book?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340021/how-to-get-coreml-in-pure-playground-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: Write `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` in front of all classes that use CoreML in your .playgroundbook

**Explanation**: Apparently, the .playgroundbook is compiled for older iOS versions despite having set the deployment target to iOS11 inside the Manifest.plist.
Using the @available prefix you can manually exclude your classes from being compiled for older versions.