# How do I get the .mlmodel to be used in Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, coreml

I have already converted the `.mlmodel` to `.mlmodelc` , and I have put it in the resources folder. Im using `Vision framework` and `MNIST` model, following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOg8AZSFvOc), but using swift playground.

What am i missing?
(im using .playground files, not .playgroundbook files)

line of code:

```
 guard let visionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: MNIST().modelc) else {fatalError("can not load Vision ML model")}
```

Error message:

> use of undefined identifier 'MNIST'

Screenshot: [image: image of playground]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playground doesn't recognize the `.mlmodel` file by default, so we need an iOS Project to help us find the compiled `mlmodelc` folder, and copy the `mlmodelc` folder to playground's resource folder, and the auto generated helper class to playground's source folder and change it to public. Then it works!

Try this project:
https://github.com/DocRace/AnimalClassifier-Swift-Playground

Answer (score 0):

The compiler raises this error, because it cannot find a declaration of the class `MNIST`, that you try to instantiate an object of.

First, create a regular Xcode project (an iOS app for example) and integrate your mlmodel there. Xcode will then generate an interface for that model automatically. These are exactly the files that are missing in your project and contain the definition of the `MNIST` class.

Clicking on the small `->` button will then lead you to these classes. Note, that in Apple's example, the model is named "MarsHabitatPricer" [image: Here you can find the generated interface classes]