# Swift Playgrounds: Use of unresolved identifier 'Model'

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-playground, coreml

First time Swift Coder here.

I'm trying to do Image Recognition using the CoreML module but when I try to run the swift playground I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'Garbage'`

This is how my file Structure looks like:

[image: file structure]

and this is the relevant code that is causing the error

```swift
private func setupCoreML() {

        //guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Garbage", withExtension: "mlmodelc") else { return }
        do {
            //let compiledUrl = try MLModel.compileModel(at: modelURL)
            let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: Garbage().model)
            self.request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, error in
                guard let observations = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { fatalError() }
                if let best = observations.first {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.label.text = "\(best.identifier): \(best.confidence)"
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

If I don't have it in a Playground page the project compiles succesfully but if I separate it into it's own Playground Page it can't find the CoreML file. I tried deleting them from different resource folders readding them,, restarting xcode but none of it worked.

The Swift Page in question is Banana

What to do?

Comment: I'm doing it for the WWDC Scholarship where it's required for me to use a playground

Comment: just came across the same issue, please do let me know if you find a fix!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340021/how-to-get-coreml-in-pure-playground-files/50466156#50466156 Seems to be the same problem

Comment: @JoRa it's not that issue. Because when I do it without the Playground Pages it seems to work but when I do it with it it doesn't